# Python scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape data from a website http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen with this filter:

```
<a class="t-bld" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:qsn.set('classtype','of',1);">nur Angebote</a>
```

How to set this filter using scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by submitting a request with the parameter and parse the result of the response. See the following code sample:

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'quoka'
    start_urls = ['http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen']

    def parse(self, response):

        request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='frmSearch',
            formdata={'classtype': 'of'},
            callback=self.parse_filtered
        )
        # print request.body
        yield request

    def parse_filtered(self,response):

        searchResults = response.xpath('//div[@id="ResultListData"]/ul/li')
        for result in searchResults:
            title = result.xpath('.//div[@class="q-col n2"]/a/@title').extract()
            print title
```

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it solved your question. Please don't use comments to post new questions, but create a new question and show the code and what you expect and what you get. See [ask] for more info.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse a specific website by using `Beautifulsoup`and `urllib2`. Here is a python implementation for the data that you wanted to parse or scrape according to the filter you wrote.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def main1(website):
    data_list = []
    web =urllib2.urlopen(website).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web)
    description = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'rel':'nofollow'})
    for de in description:
        data_list.append(de.text)
    return data_list

print main1("http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen")
```

If you wanted to parse other data such as the description from the following:

[image]

```
def main(website):
    data_list = []
    web =urllib2.urlopen(website).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web)
    description = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'description'})
    for de in description:
        data_list.append(de.text)
    return data_list

print main("http://www.quoka.de/immobilien/bueros-gewerbeflaechen") #this is the data of each section
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can only use scrapy. The only problem is that I do not know how to use filter with scrapy.